# Customizing default inputs?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, skin

I wonder if it's possible to customize my C# application (winforms) to get a better design, I made a PSD (photoshop document) so I can generate png jpeg... pictures if I need them.

Example of a form like the one I want :

[image: link]

Comment: I'll advice you to move on to WPF.

Comment: what is WPF ? I didn't get it.
EDIT:
Windows Presentation Foundation... Got it thanks!

Comment: Great. There's definitely a learning curve when moving from winforms to WPF, but for what you're trying to accomplish, It's a better option.

Comment: As mentioned by others, you're looking for WPF. winforms does not support any sort of customization (at least not without having to resort to a bunch of horrible "owner draw" hacks). It is a really old technology not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications. Newer, XAML-based technologies such as WPF and WinRT allow for much cleaner code by separating the UI from Data/application logic and also have great customizability / skinning capabilities.

Comment: I'd also like to add that you're going to have a much easier time supporting high DPI displays with WPF.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed as it was pointed out in the comments, it is easy to use WPF (indows Presentation Foundation) to achieve that result, but if you really need that it must be made in windows forms I can help you with that...

### ControlBox and Border

It seens that your form does not have a control box (minimize, maximize and close buttons)
to achieve that you can set

```
form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
```

I'm not sure if that galaxy behind your form is part of the application so i'll be considering that it is not
To achieve that irregular shape of the form we have to do a workaround here

### Irregular Shape of the Form

we are going to set a Color to TransparentKey, so everything in the form in that specific color will be transparent, like it does not exists (if you click in that part it will go into de desktop or whatever application you have behind in your form)
So let's use a specific color which we will probably dont use in the form

```
form.TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(111, 111, 111); //You can do it by the editor
```

So in order to make that white part we are going to use an **Panel** and a **PictureBox** outsite of the Panel trying to copy the shape of your image

### Stylized Inputs

To make it easier and reusable I'm going to make a userControl in this one
the usercontrol will have

- a Panel called **HighLightPanel**, its dock property will be set to Fill
- a Panel called **BackColorPanel**, it will be inside the **HighLightPanel**
- a PictureBox called **InputPicture**, its dock property will be set to Left, it will be inside **BackColorPanel** and its acessor will be public
- a TextBox called **TextBox**, its dock property wil be set to fill, it will be inside **BackColorPanel**, the BorderStyle Property set to None, you should set the size and font you most desize in this one, I'm going to use **Segoe UI; 15,75pt** and its acessor will be public

Now we have to make some properties in our UserControl to make it work without work in other controls

First in the SizeChanged event of the **HighLightPanel** we will make the BackColorPanel be exacly two points smaller in every direction and its position to 1;1 so we can see the **HighLightPanel**

```
 private void HighlightPanel_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
         this.BackColorPanel.Size = new Size(
              HighlightPanel.Width - 2, 
              HighlightPanel.Height - 2);
 }
```

Now we will create two propertys to handle the Highlight Color

```
public Color HighlightBorderColor { get; set; }
public Color NonHighlightBorderColor { get; set; }
```

And in the Enter and Leave Property of our **TextBox** we are going to change the **HighlightPanel**

```
private void TextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HighlightPanel.BackColor = HighlightBorderColor;
}
private void TextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HighlightPanel.BackColor = NonHighlightBorderColor;
}
```

So now every time the user enter the Input it will appear that the Input has an Border in the specified Color
Now to enhance its usability to developers we will make some wrappers in its controls to be easier change property of child controls in the editor

```
public Image InputImage
{
    get { return InputPicture.Image; }
    set { InputPicture.Image = value; }
}
public PictureBoxSizeMode InputImageLayout
{
    get { return InputPicture.SizeMode; }
    set { InputPicture.SizeMode = value; }
}
public char PasswordCharacter
{
    get { return TextBox.PasswordChar; }
    set { TextBox.PasswordChar = value; }
}
public bool ShowInputImage
{
    get { return InputPicture.Visible; }
    set { InputPicture.Visible = value; }
}
```

In the InputImage set the picture you want for the User and the Key
Insert the two controls in the position you like

### Position of the Form

if you want your form to be moveable without the border you will have to use this snippet, it is more easy in WPF

```
#region MoveForm
Point LastPoint;
bool ShouldMove;
private void form_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    LastPoint = e.Location;
    ShouldMove = true;
    this.TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(111, 111, 111);
}
private void form_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ShouldMove = false;
}
private void form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (ShouldMove)
    {
        this.Location = new Point(
             this.Location.X - LastPoint.X + e.X, 
             this.Location.Y - LastPoint.Y + e.Y);
    }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need a lot of special graphics effects learning WPF will indeed be a sound investement.

If all you want is that login screen, it is trivial in Winforms and doesn't take any horrible hacks as you've been told..

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LavenderBlush;
this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.LavenderBlush;
this.ControlBox = false;
this.MaximizeBox = false;
this.MinimizeBox = false;
this.Text= "";
```

These seven lines are all it takes for a form to be transparent. I copied them from the Designer code; you can simply set the 7 Properties in the property grid.

Now add a panel, dock it to the bottom and give it the right color; add a picturebox and your other controls and you are set.

To create the two input groups you also need just a few regular controls and only a few simple lines of code:

You place one Panel, `BorderStyle = FixedSingle;` and add a Label and a TextBox to it. The Label  has `AutoSize = False;` and both `ImageAlign` and `TextAlign` are set to `MiddleLeft`. You assign an image to the Label's `Image` and prefix the `Text` with enough blanks to not overlap. Obviously you should define a `PasswordChar` for the 2nd TextBox. Now all you need is to script the `Enter` and `Leave` events to change the BackColor of the respective Panels between, say `SystemColors.Control` and `SystemColors.MenuHighlight`. Size the Labels to almost fill the Panels and you are done. Less code than the WPF version, I'd bet.

If you need such input an controls again and again, simply create Usercontrols for each type you need!

Here is an example of the **limits** you will hit: Wouldn't it be nice to add a dropshadow effect to the image? It is doable in Winforms. But it would involve painting that effect; this would take at least 15 or 20 lines of involved code instead of simply turning the effect on with (estimated) 1-3 simple lines.

Do you need any nice hover effects? Not easy, to say the least..

These limits will be all over the place, so it really depends on how fancy your requirements will get.

Maybe you should use this example as a starter to compare the two techniques and to warm you up to WPF?

Comment: -1 your answer does not show how to do the OP's desired UI. You're also not taking into account the ">"-shaped visual between the icons and the input boxes, and the button and Checkbox themes, which do require a bunch of horrible "owner draw" crap in winforms. There's NO way you can achieve this in winforms with "less code than the WPF version" as you said, if you really think so, post the code here and I'll post a link to my WPF version so we can compare which code is shorter.

Comment: Not to mention that I'm adivicing the OP against useless dinosaur winforms not only because current technologies are much more capable, but also because XAML based technologies *encourage* a proper separation of UI and data/application logic (which is always desirable) as opposed to the winforms approach which vomits a bunch of code behind with zero reuse / scale possibilities.

Comment: As usual nothing you say is true and everything you seem to know about Winforms is deficient. The little deco (if that's what it is) can be part of the image. The code is __4__ lines of code for the color changes. I see no Checkbox or Button style that goes beyond the usualy properties, etc, etc, etc. And most importantly: I have advised to go WPF. From the first to the last line of my answer. Which you, as usual, ignore, blinded by your irrational hatred in the presence of anthing Winforms. -1? Shrug..!